Error in iOS Simulator with .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid: "Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion
I am developing a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid application in Visual Studio 2022 and encountering an error when attempting to run it on the iOS simulator.
The error message states: The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion. I have tried adding the CFBundleVersion to my Info.plist as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your location to provide earthquake alerts for you.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>

The error occurs and the application fails to launch. Here are the error logs:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
    Failed to install the requested application
    The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.shakesafe' on the device 'iOS 17.2 (21C62) - iPad Air (5th generation)': simctl returned exit code 22

My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>ShakeSafe</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>ShakeSafe</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.shakesafe</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
      <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#99C24D" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Resources\Icons\report_icon.svg" />
        <None Remove="Resources\Fonts\Nunito-VariableFont_wght.ttf" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Resources\Icons\home_icon.svg">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Resources\Icons\info_icon.svg">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Resources\Icons\map_icon.svg">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Resources\Icons\report_icon.svg">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Resources\Icons\settings_icon.svg">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Necessary NuGet packages for MAUI -->
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Maps" Version="8.0.21" />
        <!-- Firebase packages -->
        <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAdmin" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="FirebaseDatabase.net" Version="4.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <BundleResource Include="Resources\Fonts\Nunito-VariableFont_wght.ttf" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="wwwroot\data\gem_active_faults_harmonized.geojson">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiAsset Update="Resources\Raw\AboutAssets.txt">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </MauiAsset>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have tried:

Resetting the simulator.

Testing on different devices.

Adding a CFBundleVersion.


App builds when I create a new project with the template.

Try 1.0.0 instead.

What is in your csproj? There is a version number in there that is used to populate this value as well

1.0.0 did not work either @trojanfoe

I added my csproj file to the question @GeraldVersluis

You can try to set the <key>CFBundleVersion</key>      <string>1.0</string>      <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>      <string>1</string> to three unsigned integers, separated by periods, because Apple has some specific requirements for the format of version numbers: build version number.

You can check if the version settings in the project‘s .csproj file matchs the version in the info.plist file. The  in the csproj file matches the Version in the info.plist file, and the  matches the Build.

You can check your project by following the steps below

Ensure the version settings in the project's csproj file match the
version in the info.plist file.
The Application Display Version in the csproj file matches the
Version in the info.plist file, and the Application Version
matches the Build.
You can refer to Information property list to learn about the
relationship between info.plist file and .csproj file.

According to the solution in the Cannot launch ios app on simulator
or device "does not contain valid CFBundleVersion", the problem
may not be caused by the version setting.
If relevant resources are added to the Resources folder of your
project, you can try to temporarily delete or replace them to check
whether the error will disappear.

Check whether all packages in the project have been successfully
added to the project, such as GoogleService-Info.This may also cause
your error


For other possible causes of the error, you can refer to the answer in The bundle's Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleVersion key. Many of the answers indicate that there are many reasons that can cause this error. You can try the solutions according to your project.
